# Jquery Cannot get the outerHeight of a hidden footer

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a footer which should auto-reveal using a javascript function depending upon its outerHeight() but it doesn't .. debugging I get null value..

```
    <section class="z-index-1 pull-bottom-fixed full-width" data-pages="reveal-footer">

         <section>
            <div class="container">
             <dv class="row"></div>
             <dv class="row"></div>
           </div
         </section>

          <section>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row"></div>
              <dv class="row"></div>
           </div>
          </section>

    </section>
```

Here is the reveal-footer function

```
    Pages.prototype.initRevealFooter = function() {
        var _elem = $('[data-pages="reveal-footer"]');
        setHeight();
        function setHeight(){
                var h = _elem.outerHeight();
                _elem.prev().css({
                     'margin-bottom':h
                })
        }
        $(window).resize(function(){
            setHeight();
        })
    }
```

When I check the _elem.outerHeight()  I get null ...

I am using the latest JQuery version ( 1.11.3 )
I read the jQuery down about outerHeight() ...

UPDATE

the resizing is working fine ( sliders appear, and I can scroll to the bottom to see the footer )  on FF and Chrome on OS X BUT not on Safari ..

so Safari doesn't like this piece of code

```
Pages.prototype.initRevealFooter = function() {
    var _elem = $('[data-pages="reveal-footer"]');
    setHeight();
    function setHeight(){
            var h = _elem.outerHeight();
            _elem.prev().css({
                 'margin-bottom':h
            })
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        setHeight();
    })        
}
```

Comment: Simple reason why...hidden elements have no dimensions or page offset. Browser can only measure what it displays

Comment: jQuery states :  The value reported by .outerHeight() is not guaranteed to be accurate when the element or its parent is hidden. To get an accurate value, ensure the element is visible before using .outerHeight(). jQuery will attempt to temporarily show and then re-hide an element in order to measure its dimensions, but this is unreliable and (even when accurate) can significantly impact page performance. This show-and-rehide measurement feature may be removed in a future version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only code you have on the page than like @charlietfl commented - there is no height if the elements have no content or styling..

You should post some more code.

check out this pen for an example that works ->  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPjjYg

CSS

```
[data-pages="reveal-footer"]{
  height: 10px;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

JS

```
 _g = jQuery('[data-pages="reveal-footer"]');
g.css({'border': '1px solid blue'});
var hh = g.outerHeight();  //returns 12
```

Comment: I updated my question ... the js code works fine with FF( 37.0.1)  and Chrome ( 44.0) on OS X  but not with Safari ( 8.0.8)

Comment: great. you should mark your answer as correct. [and vote up if helped] cheers.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue after testing the same code in Chrome, FF and Safari...
working fine w FF and Chrome , but not with Safari

I modified the css... inserting overflow: auto  in the body tag ...

```
 /*[1. Layouts] */
 html,
 body {
    height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

This solved the issue ... the footer can now be displayed , nothing wrong neither in the html code neither in the js code ... only CSS default for overflow !  dont' know why Safari default to no
 and FF/Chrome default to yes